# Leaflet - weird looking map with circle shapes

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I was using an outdated veriosn of leaflet 1.0.0. 
Updated to the newest version 1.6.0 and I'm observing odd behaviour at different zoom levels.

[Illustration of this behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhsq9.png)

The larger the zoom, the more precise the diameters are.

I'am using L.Circle with constant radius and equals 0.14

Tried scaling everything and switching between canvas and svg rendering engine.

Comment: Can you pls share your code and/or create a fiddle

Comment: Here is sample code I just created from scratch, and I see the same behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/qmcer3xL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured out a workaround to this problem in leaflet-src.js:

changed:

```
 _round: function () {
    this.x = Math.round(this.x);
    this.y = Math.round(this.y);
    return this;
 },
```

to just:

```
_round: function () {
    return this;
},
```

it works for me.

Comment: FWIW, this sounds to be a similar issue as [Leaflet/Leaflet #4745](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4745)

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle you are useing a old version of leaflet:

`http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js`
should be:
`https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js`

`http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css`
should be:
`https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css`

After I updated leaflet, the circles showing correct

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake, I've just updated the fiddle and now I see again that problem It relates to very small radius, try and zoom that white dot: http://jsfiddle.net/nh1cgepb/

Comment: it looks like it is to small for the renderer. http://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/r6knvgo1/ @IvanSanchez Do you know this problem?